# Spring with HSQLDB latest 2.4.0 version not working

Tags: java, spring, maven, hsqldb, dao

I am trying to create simple Java 1.7 project for Spring with HSQL DB. 
I downloaded latest version of HSQL DB and created a simple file based DB.

In java project I am using latest version of Spring, HSQL and related jar. But while running program I am getting error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 bad major version; class=org/hsqldb/jdbcDriver, offset=6
```

My file is

```
        <!-- Spring framework -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
        <dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
<version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
<version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/cglib/cglib -->
        <dependency>
<groupId>cglib</groupId>
<artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
<version>3.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-dbcp2 -->
        <dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
<version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hsqldb/hsqldb -->
        <dependency>
<groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
<artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
<version>2.4.0</version>
```

What should be change in jars ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HSQLDB 2.4.0 has been compiled with JDK 8 and cannot be used with JDK 7 or earlier.

You need to specify version 2.3.5 for a version that has been compiled with JDK 6. This version lacks the new JDBC features introduced in Java 8 but is compatible with version 2.4.0 in other respects.

Comment: Used HSQL DB 2.3.4 . Worked well., Thanks.

Comment: Try 2.3.5. It is even better.